# Express JS "Put" and getting error of duplicated Ids

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express

I am learning Express and connecting my app to PostgreSQL db. It's an ecommerce store page, so I have product catalog db and user cart tables. Each table has product id, product name, product description, etc... and then catalog table has product_stock and user cart has product_quantity.
I wanted to update the product quantity in cart by using "put" method. So when I have the button add to cart, it checks if the object already exists in the cart, if not it adds the object to user cart table, if it already exist it should update the quantity.

My server index.js (put part):

```
app.get('/cart-products/:product_id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { product_id } = req.params;
    const getProduct = await pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM user_product WHERE product_id = $1', [product_id]
    );
    res.json(getProduct.rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

app.put('/cart-products/:product_id', async (req,res) => {
  try {
   const { product_id } = req.params;
   const {product_quantity} = req.body;
   const updatedQuantity = await pool.query("UPDATE user_product SET product_quantity = $1 WHERE product_id = $2", [product_quantity, product_id]);
   res.json('updated quantity')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
})
```

and client side function:

```
 const addToCart = (product) => {
  if (!checkIfRepeatedInCart(product.product_id))
  {
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/cart-products', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      product_id: product.product_id,
      product_name: product.product_name,
      product_description: product.product_description,
      product_price: product.product_price,
      product_cat: product.product_cat,
      product_stock: product.product_stock,
      product_url: product.product_url,
      product_quantity: 1
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
   else {
    const newQuantity = product.product_quantity + 1;
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/cart-products/${product.product_id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },    
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product_quantity: newQuantity,
        product_id: product.product_id
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }  
}
;
 const checkIfRepeatedInCart = (index) => {
      let repeatedItemInCart = itemsAddedToCartList.find((product)=> product.id === index);
      return repeatedItemInCart;
    }
```

post and delete functions work fine, so I can add and delete the product from the cart, but when I try to add second item of the same product, I get an nodemon error:

```
  length: 209,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: 'Key (product_id)=(4) already exists.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'user_product',
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: 'user_product_pkey',
  file: 'nbtinsert.c',
  line: '670',
  routine: '_bt_check_unique'
}
```

I don't understand why it's saying that I'm duplicating the product id, if I'm not posting the object, just trying the put method. Should I have two separate functions for add to cart?

Comment: There seems to be multiple problems with your code. I'm not even sure how it is supposed to work. Where is your user in your user_product table, or in any of your code? Currently it seems like a single-user online store, as the data in your examples doesn't contain any user id. Have you considered using an ORM like TypeORM or Sequelize that would help you construct working queries, and TypeScript to know the types of your data? (Also, the data sent by client doesn't match what the server is using and without any input validation you are only asking for trouble.)

Comment: @rsp I wanted to check behaviour first before adding user authentication, that's why it doesn't have any user id yet. I will check the tools you recommend.